# ADO SQLServer dbGo generates a EAccessViolation

Tags: ado, sql-server-2005-express

I have a program that is filling a DB in a single thread.
I Use one connection for all queries. Thats so i will be able to run them all in transactions.

Every second I get a new set of files that has to be entered into a SQL Server 2005 Express.

The Application can run for 24 to 36 hours and than suddenly get a "EAccessViolation" in a query.

This query is by then been executed for atleast 24 * 60 * 60 times.

I'm not shure if it also happens with querys without parameres because most of the queries (90%) has parameres. they are inserts/updates or select with a parameter(s).

when this occures all queries afterwards get the same EAccessViolation and after a while I get a StackOverflow.

While the code is constructed in sutch a manner that an exception will be handled and the next time the code should run without problems.

the fact that this is happening in varios queries (that did't change from the former version) with the only change that in stead of using dbGo from BCB Builder 2007 we did ADO with Cpp Builder 6.0.

I asume that it is someware in the Windows version MDAC(2.8) or in de dbGo from CodeGear. The fact that in the previous version (ADO BCB6.0)we did't run into it and now with (dbGO and BCB2007) we have is it making that part very suspicius.

I hope that some has some nice Ideas what could be the reason for all this.

At the moment I Can't reproduce it here on a desktop. I'm still trying to get it reproduced that will defibnitly give more info.

I'm open for suggestions.

regards

jvdn.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the driver - try using a different one to see if the problem can be isolated. Also try to rewrite the query to use a different syntax, maybe you could recyle the connections every so often?

Comment: I hope this will show,

The Windows machines are the same (Driver) I did find some extra Errror object in the ADOConn. This one I will explore futrther on.
Thanks for your reaction.